# updating JSTL Locale dynamically irrespective of browser locale setting

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl, locale

I am developing web app using `spring mvc` frame work, in one of my jsp page i have `<fmt:formatNumber> JSTL formatting tag`. Usally this formatting tag will take `locale information from client's browser locale setting`. But i want to use `specific locale` not from browser locale setting. How can i do it.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place

```
<fmt:setLocale value="Your_Local"/>
```

before your

```
<fmt:formatNumber>
```

and the switch back to browser locale

```
<fmt:setLocale value="${request.getLocale}"/>
```